# App Crashing in Kitkat 4.4.2

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, android-4.4-kitkat

I am new to Android and new to this forum as well. I have done an Android app and it is running fine in Android Lollipop and Marshmallow. However when I try to open my app from Android Kitkat, the app is not opening up. Its suddenly closing by itself. I am of the feeling the it is due to the improper minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion. My build.gradle is as below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'XX'
            keyPassword 'XXX777'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/XXX/XXXXX.jks')
            storePassword 'XXX777'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fire.firebasetest.testone"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 4
        versionName "4.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // volley
    // Glide
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My app has a splash screen on start and its not opening up in Kitkat 4.4.

My manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <application
        android:name=".AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_new"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Can someone help me out to solve this issue?

Comment: Please add you stacktrace

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: I am unable to do USB debugging from my phone. So what else can be done?